# Problema com o efeito .blur() do JQuery no IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Possuo um método de construção de elementos dinâmicos utilizando jQuery v1.2 com Ajax, que cria uma lista de itens contendo a estrutura de `<ul>` e `<li>`, porém, quando aplico o `.blur()` e o Ajax retorna muitos valores, é criado uma  barra de rolagem. No IE8 quando clico na barra de rolagem o `.blur()` é acionado.

Nos outros navegadores funciona sem problemas, porém, apenas no IE8 tenho este problema.

Aqui está um cídigo que eu criei no codePen: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/CleberOtaviano/pen/gyrhJ)

Eu preferi pelo CodePen pois não consegui utilizar o JsFiddle.

Comment: Se você roda seu código no JsFiddle usando uma versão mais atual da jQuery o problema ainda acontece?

Comment: Gostaria de ver o código em questão para fazer testes

Comment: O código no CodePen http://codepen.io/CleberOtaviano/pen/gyrhJ

Comment: Quando eu clico na scrollbar das opções/sugestões o blur() é disparado em todos os browsers. E isso faz sentido visto eu clicar fora do elemento input. É isso que você quer evitar?

Comment: Sergio, o que você falou faz todo sentido, pensando no que você disse, alterei de .blur() para uma verificação, se onde foi clicado foi diferente da lista então realiza o "display none" da lista. Muito obrigado. Segue alteração no CodePen: http://goo.gl/j14Iho

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
 window.onload = function blur(){
   var name = document.getElementById('idname');
   var name2 = document.getElementById('idname2');

 name.addEventistener('click', function(){
    name2.style.msFilter = "blur(XXpx)"
 });
 }
 </script>
```

EXPLICAÇÃO: 
Na var name voce define o elemento que quizer por meio do ID. na var name2 voce define outro. quando clicar no name o name2 irá ficar com style do filtro blur.

Comment: Poderia dar um breve resumo do que faz o seu código?

Comment: Na var name voce define o elemento que quizer por meio do ID.      na var name2 voce define outro. quando clicar no name o name2 irá ficar com style do filtro blur.

Comment: Edite sua resposta com esse comentário. (: